# Fitting a gaussian process with unknown data scale

Tags: gaussian-process

I have to repeatedly fit a gaussian process to experimental data where the scale of that data may vary. That is, each experiment has data multiplied by a different value of $C$. Now, I know the expected form of the covariance - let's say it's square exponential $k(x,y) = \exp\left[-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]$ with no additional independent noise. In that case, how should the scaling factor affect $k$? Should $\sigma$ be scaled or $k$ just multiplied by C? Of course I don't know $C$ so I would a attempt to fit it.

I do believe that $\sigma$ itself is independent of the specific experiment so I'm just not sure where to put the scale factor.

**Edit**: put it another way, suppose you fit a GP to some data points with the SE covariance function written above, and obtain $\sigma_0$. Now multiply all the points by $C$. If you fit again with the same covariance, what do you obtain for $\sigma$? If you wanted the fit to obtain the same $\sigma$, should you multiply $k$ by $C$?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "multiply the points" by a constant.  Would that refer to (a) changing the units of measure of $x$ and $y$ or (b) rescaling the values of the process?  If your answer is (a), doesn't that immediately tell you what to do with $\sigma$?  And if it's (b), why should $\sigma$ change at all?

Comment: @whuber Changing the units. And it looks like you're right, I experimented with changing the scale and $\sigma$ varied correctly. Thanks!